# Wildcard and Fuzzy query together in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard, fuzzy-search

I am trying to design a query in which, I can use wildcard and Fuzzy query together.

According to me, query_string is used for wildcard searches and multi_match can be used for fuzziness.

I want a query which will search on words :-

"elast" : - provide results elastic and elasticsearch.
"elasttc" :- also provide results as elastic and elasticsearch.

Elastic search supports wildcard and fuzzy query together??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "testing"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "title": "*testing*"
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "title": "testing"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @David, your query works fine but according to your query only one of them can be used at a time, i.e I query will use only fuzzy or only wildcard for searching. Is their any way I can use both of them together? It is possible or not??

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with Query String with wildcards. The suffix `~AUTO*` enables a prefix query with fuzzy, also you can use the fields selection like `multi_match` query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["name^2", "content^1"],
            "query" : "elasttc~AUTO*"
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the `AUTO` keyword with a numeric value too, as the same `fuzziness` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo, but your query is not providing desired results. It is providing me all results. Like if I search on *name* field using _elasttc~AUTO*_ , I can also see results of _lucene_ in name field.

Comment: @Pranav, try to include the parameter analyze_wildcard: true. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Yeah, this just gets everything. The `analyze_wildcard` parameter has no effect.